# How do i style an MVC 5 dropdown to match bootstrap?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

This is my code but I can't for the life of me figure out how to style this guy:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.HousingType, new SelectList(new List<Object>
                        {
                            new { value = "Rent", text = "Rent"},
                            new { value = "Own", text = "Own"},
                            new { value = "Live with parents", text = "Live with parents"},
                        },
                            "value",
                            "text",
                            2
                            ))

                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.HousingType)
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace your dropdownlistfor razor code with this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.HousingType, new SelectList(new List<Object>
                        {
                            new { value = "Rent", text = "Rent"},
                            new { value = "Own", text = "Own"},
                            new { value = "Live with parents", text = "Live with parents"},
                        },
                            "value",
                            "text",
                            2
                                ), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

It is always good to refer to overloads when working with asp.net mvc HTML Helpers. [This is the link for DropDownListFor Helper.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) Intellisense in Visual studio can also help you as you start typing/edit.